# Interaction terms in tbl_regression in R

Tags: gtsummary

How do I include coefficient of interaction between age and stage

```
  glm(response~age+grade, family=binomial(link=logit),
data=trial) %>%
tbl_regression(
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)
  )
```

Comment: Hi Magut, Can you give more details here?  The `tbl_uvregression()` function constructs univariable regression models and therefore would not include interaction terms. Please add an example data of what you'd like to see.

Comment: modified. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `tbl_regression()` functions provides a summary of the model results. To include an interaction in the summary table, the interaction must first be added to the model. Example below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

tbl <- 
  glm(response ~ age * grade, family = binomial, data=trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>